# How to declare a variable only once in Gamemaker Step function?

Tags: game-maker-studio-1.4

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leGme.png)

I want the variable maxx to only update once when calling this script and all the other lines of code every frame , please help

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Declare the variable in Create
- Structure the script so that it is called in Create to initialize it and then in Step to use it
  (an optional argument or lack of arguments for a reasonable solution, `event_type` for a hack)
- Use `variable_instance_exists` provided that you are not using an ancient version of GMS1